# Maximum likelihood variance estimator of simple linear regression is biased

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

Colleagues, I understand that bias is defined as $b(\theta)=\mathbb{E}(\hat{\theta})-\theta$. How can one show that the variance estimator for maximum likelihood estimators of simple simple linear regression is biased?

The estimator is given by
$$ \sigma ^2 =  \frac{1}{n}  \sum  (Y_i -\hat{\beta}_0 -\hat{\beta}_1 X_i)^2$$

Comment: Start by writing down the variance estimator and take the expectation? edit your post to include your working.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh, I have done the did

Comment: perhaps consider what do you know about $\hat{\beta}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume normality of the error term, then you can use the $\chi^2$ distribution. Namely,
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n( y_i - \hat\beta_0 - \hat\beta_1x_i)^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n( y_i - \hat\beta_0 - \hat\beta_1x_i)^2/\sigma^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}\chi^2(n-2) , 
$$
where the expected value of $\chi^2(n-2)$ is $n-2$.

Comment: this is great work